# Converting ichat file into text format using applescript or any other script

Tags: text, applescript, ichat

> I recently received several .ichat archived logs.

I am using Windows 7 and I wanted to know if there was any way to view or convert these files so I would be able to read them on my PC.

I've tried using different formats such as HTML and txt.

I have had no luck in seeing the contents of the files, I searched all over the internet with no luck so this is my last resort.

Please respond if you know any way that I can open these files.

Comment: Hi there, I found this: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/72987/how-can-i-convert-ichat-logs-to-text-files